Swagger UI not working in prod mode when quarkus.vertx.classpath-resolving is disabled in Quarkus 3.12.0
In prod mode swagger-ui works when classpath resolving is enabled but not when it is disabled.
Specifically, this property value stops swagger-ui from working:
quarkus.vertx.classpath-resolving=false

With this value in prod mode, the service returns a 404 because index.html cannot be found in the swagger folder.
Are there any workarounds?
Enabling this feature would not work in my case since we are forbidding file system writes for security reasons, and setting the value to true causes the service to write to a temporary folder.
Quarkus version 3.12.0
Additional context

I have set the quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include property to true.
When running in production mode with Vert.x classpath resolving enabled, the Swagger UI renders correctly.
Disabling Vert.x classpath resolving causes a 404 error on the Swagger UI URL, with the service logging that /index.html was not found.


I don't think there is a workaround. You can try and copy the index.html to you project, not sure of that will work

@PhillipKrüger there was a workaround in the end, and it was as you suggested.
I copied all the swagger-ui html files in my resources/META-INF/resources folder and only had to adjust one file (swagger-initializer.js) by adjusting the SwaggerUIBundle url property.
Thanks for your help.
